# Why does converting a bitmap to 8bpp result in 224 entries instead of 256?

Tags: c#, bitmap, color-palette, pixelformat

I am trying to convert an existing bitmap to a palette which has 256 colours.

After researching on the web, people suggest:

```
Bitmap b1 = new Bitmap(picture);
Bitmap b2 = new Bitmap(b1.Size.Width,
                       b1.Size.Height,
                       System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
```

When I debug and check the number of entries, it has set the PixelFormat to 256, but the palette only contains 224 entries

Comment: Is it possible that there are only 224 color values in the original image?

Comment: @MichaelTodd: That shouldn't matter, since he's not using the original image to create the new bitmap. Just the size of the original image.

Answer (score 0):

What version are you using? This code, compiled in debug mode with Visual Studio 2010 (.NET 4.0), gives me a palette with 256 entries.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var b1 = new Bitmap(BITMAP_NAME);
    var b2 = new Bitmap(b1.Width, b1.Height, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
    int numColors = b2.Palette.Entries.Length;
    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Palette contains {0} entries", numColors));
    b2.Dispose();
    b1.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Hi, Yes, the above code shows 256 entries in palette but my requirement is to convert existing non-indexed bitmap to 8bpp indexed. I have used the code like this: Bitmap indexedBitmap = originalBmp.Clone(new Rectangle(0, 0, originalBmp.Width, originalBmp.Height), System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed); But this results in 224 entries, how do I fix this?